# MVC3 Editor Template for List Not Populating

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, editortemplates, mvc-editor-templates

Problem: When I load the EditorTemplate for UserModel the UserRoles list does not generate a list of UserRole editors.

My models:

```
    public class UserSearchModel
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("User Roles")]
    public UserRoles UserRoles { get; set; }
}

    public partial class UserRoles : List<UserRole>
{

}

    public class UserRole
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

My editor Templates:

```
@model eGate.BackOffice.WebClient.Model.UserModel
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.UserName)
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.UserName)
<h1>roles</h1>
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.UserRoles)



@model eGate.BackOffice.WebClient.Model.UserRole
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.RoleName)
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.IsChecked)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.IsChecked)
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Description)
```

*Actual Output Looks like:*

User Name [ someuser ]

**roles**

*Expected Output:*

User Name [ someuser ]

**roles**

role1 
[x] ischecked
role for 1

role2 
[x] ischecked
role for 2

role3 
[x] ischecked
role for 3

Comment: You need to provide more information.  What is your EditorTamplate called, where did you put it?

Answer (score 0):

You should just make the type List rather than deriving your own type.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that the problem is the definition of `UserRoles` as a separate class.  Try changing the property `UserRoles` in the `UserSearchModel` class to:

```
public List<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
```

MVC is searching for a template for the `UserRoles` class.  Since the template is for the `UserRole` class, MVC fails to find any template.

**UPDATE**

Also, I overlooked that you are using `EditorFor` for the UserRoles model.  You should use `EditorForModel` like so:

```
@Html.EditorForModel(m => m.UserRoles)
```

Comment: Just for the sake of not ruling anything out I gave that a try. But still no dice.

Answer (score 0):

This issue looks to be more likely caused by the fact the User EditorTemplate is being served up by the popUp window of a telerik mvc grid.

I have tested outside the grid popup to find that the templates work as expected. I will close this question and re-ask the correct question in another entry.

Comment: I had some problems with editor template and telerik as well, it wasn't generating the template while referenced inside the grid